# Generate a string array from a union type typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Hi guys I am looking for a way to get an array from a union typescript type

This is an existing  type :

```
 export type GridClassKey =
  | 'root'
  | 'container'
  | 'item'
  | 'zeroMinWidth'
  | 'direction-xs-column'
  | 'direction-xs-column-reverse'
  | 'direction-xs-row-reverse'
  | 'wrap-xs-nowrap'
  | 'wrap-xs-wrap-reverse'
  | 'align-items-xs-center'
  | 'align-items-xs-flex-start'
  | 'align-items-xs-flex-end'
  | 'align-items-xs-baseline'
  | 'align-content-xs-center'
  | 'align-content-xs-flex-start'
  | 'align-content-xs-flex-end'
  | 'align-content-xs-space-between'
  | 'align-content-xs-space-around'
  | 'justify-xs-center'
  | 'justify-xs-flex-end'
  | 'justify-xs-space-between'
  | 'justify-xs-space-around'
  | 'justify-xs-space-evenly'
  | 'spacing-xs-1'
  | 'spacing-xs-2'
  | 'spacing-xs-3'
  | 'spacing-xs-4'
  | 'spacing-xs-5'
  | 'spacing-xs-6'
  | 'spacing-xs-7'
  | 'spacing-xs-8'
  | 'spacing-xs-9'
  | 'spacing-xs-10'
  | 'grid-xs-auto'
  | 'grid-xs-true'
  | 'grid-xs-1'
  | 'grid-xs-2'
  | 'grid-xs-3'
  | 'grid-xs-4'
  | 'grid-xs-5'
  | 'grid-xs-6'
  | 'grid-xs-7'
  | 'grid-xs-8'
  | 'grid-xs-9'
  | 'grid-xs-10'
  | 'grid-xs-11'
  | 'grid-xs-12'
```

I would like to get programmatically a real string array from it, something like :

```
['root','container', ...]
```

is it possible, since GridClassKey is a type and not a value ?

Thank you

Comment: No, it's not, because you cannot assemble an array at runtime if types don't exist at runtime.

Comment: I remember seeing an NPM library that generated files with arrays based on types exactly like this. I can't find it now though. I wish I could.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no way that we can create an array from the type because we cannot assemble an array at runtime if types don't exist at runtime (@Ingo Bürk's comment). But we can do the reverse. If we have a const array, we can get a union type for it. For example-

```js
const gridClassKeys = ['root', 'container'] as const

// "root" | "container"
type GridClassKey = typeof gridClassKeys[number]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gJwJYBMDCAbAhhCBpAUwE8IYBeGAbQHIEQQpqAaGa0MKLJMAhagXRg4Y7aACgxAekkwARHQayYAHzntO3XrLFQiABwIwA4snTZchIuRi6DIAGbxTmHPmIRKYAK4BbAEa8-EA)

Please note, we have to use [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) while declaring the array (the array will be readlonly tuple, therefore fixed keys)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I only have these types as data source :/  too bad... Thanks for the answer !

Comment: @Topsy If the types are in a file, you can do file manipulation to retrieve the array.

Comment: It's a typescript file from material ui node modules ^^ So I don't really want to do that. But it's ok I did it manually ^^thanks

Comment: @Topsy, yeh, that will not be a good idea