# Filter out array values that are not in a literal union type

Tags: typescript, type-erasure, union-types

For example, I have a literal string union type:

```
type AllowedColor = 'red' | 'blue';
```

And I'm receiving the color from the server.

```
let colors = getColorsFromServer();
```

I want to filter the array to only consist of `AllowedColor` type. This is a pseudo code that is not working:

```
colors.filter(color => color is AllowedColor);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a string array from a union type typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66751035/generate-a-string-array-from-a-union-type-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Type aliases don't exist at runtime

You can't use a type alias in any runtime logic because of [type erasure](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types). `type AllowedColor` will not exist in the generated Javascript.[1] Typescript types have only one role: static type checking logic.

### You have to approach it from the other direction

#### type derived from a const array

Instead of runtime logic or data depending on static type information, have static type information depend on runtime data:

```js
// values available at runtime
const allowedColors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'] as const

// type available at compile time, equivalent to:
//     type AllowedColor = 'red' | 'blue' | 'green'
type AllowedColor = typeof allowedColors[number]
```

#### defining a Typescript type guard

You could then define a convenient `isAllowedColor` validation function that serves double-duty as a Typescript type guard:

```js
function isAllowedColor(color:string): color is AllowedColor {
    return (allowedColors as unknown as string[]).includes(color)
}
```

#### type derived from an enum

If an `allowedColors` `enum` would be more useful than the array above:

```js
// values available at runtime
enum allowedColors {red = 'red', blue = 'blue', green = 'green'}

// type available at compile time, equivalent to
//     type AllowedColor = 'red' | 'blue' | 'green'
type AllowedColor = typeof allowedColors[keyof typeof allowedColors]

// a validation function that also acts as a Typescript type guard
function isAllowedColor(color:string): color is AllowedColor {
    return color in allowedColors
}
```

#### usage

```js
let someColors = ['red', 'blue', 'chartreuse', 'teal', 'ocher']

// because isAllowedColor is also a type guard, we are using the version
// of Array<T>.filter that accepts a type guard predicate, with a return
// type of T[], in this case AllowedColor[]
let filteredColors: AllowedColor[] = someColors.filter(isAllowedColor)

console.log(filteredColors)  // [ 'red', 'blue' ]
```

Comment: @Stucky, thanks for the accept. You made me relook at my answer, and I improved it slightly with the use of type guards (as first suggested by captain-yossarian, though without violating DRY and without the use of regex). Both my previous version and this work the same and yields essentially the exact same JS, so you can use either.

Answer (score 0):

For now, my workaround for this is:

```
const allowedColors = ['red', 'blue'] as const;
type AllowedColor = typeof allowedColors[number];

let colors = getColorsFromServer();
colors.filter(color => allowedColors.includes(color));
```

Let me know if you know better approach

Answer (score 0):

It worth using [typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), since `Array.prototype.filter` expects a [predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230944/what-does-predicate-mean-in-the-context-of-computer-science) as an argument.

Consider this example:

```js
type AllowedColor = 'red' | 'blue';

const getColorsFromServer = () => {
  let color: string[] = ['green', 'red', 'blue']
  return color;
}

let colors = getColorsFromServer();

const isAllowed = (color: string): color is AllowedColor => /red|blue/.test(color)

// const isAllowed = (color: string): color is AllowedColor =>  ['red', 'blue'].includes(color)

const result = colors.filter(isAllowed) //  AllowedColor[]
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N7KjBN)

Comment: Whenever a new color is added to the allowed list, you have to add it in two places, to the `AllowedColor` type alias, and to the `/red|blue/.test(color)` regex test. That's very not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) (search for "dry principle" on the web for lots of articles. Also, I don't like the use of regex as a type check.

Comment: @Inigo this is why I have provided an alternative solution. See commented line below `const isAllowed`. In fact, your `isAllowedColor` is a duplicate of mine. I know what DRY means, thank you